# Python: From arg parser to dictionary

Tags: python, json, argparse

I have a file in Python 3.8 called "stores.py" This file has a method called "scan_transactions" which takes 2 positional arguments: "store" and "checkpoint". The method basically scans for store transactions in a PostgreSQL table by making use of REGEX patterns. When the code reaches the last transaction id for that particular store in the transactions table, another table (checkpoint table) is then used and updated to indicate what is the latest max transaction id for any given store.

At the moment I am passing both arguments from a pre-defined dictionary similar to the one below:

```
dict_stores = {'store1': 'checkpoint_store1', 'store2': 'checkpoint_store2','store3': 'checkpoint_store3'}
```

Currently the code is looking like the below:

```
def store_transactions(store: str, checkpoint_name: str)
.
.
.
.
.

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for store, checkpoint in shops.dict_stores.items():
        LOG.debug(f'Processing store : {store}, checkpoint: {checkpoint}')
        store_transactions(store, checkpoint)
```

I am now looking to make this more dynamic and allow the user to pass the stores they want to process the transactions for as a batch job right before they execute it. This would be using the command line below:

```
"stores.py" --stores -store1 -store2 -store3...etc.
```

The command above would then replace this pre-fixed dictionary and create a dictionary dynamically. Does anyone know how I could use "arg parser" to somehow programatically convert the arguments "-shop 1", "-shop2" into a dictionary like the one above (with their respective checkpoints as values) and process all stores with the same loop I am currently running with?

Comment: This seems more like a list; and that's the default behaviour

Comment: Hi @crissal can you elaborate a bit further please?

Comment: The `argparse` documentation explains that `args=parser.parse_args()` parses the `sys.argv` list (from the shell/interpreter), and returns a `Namespace` object.  `vars(args)` converts that object to a `dict`.  You can easily fetch values from either.  Also instead of the `sys.argv`, you can pass a similar list of strings.

Comment: The first example in [Adding Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#adding-arguments) seems like what you want. Its form would be `supermarkets.py --stores store1 store2 ...`. Its minus the single dashes, but you don't want single dashes which traditionally demark single character flags.

Comment: So, basically, you want to pass in a list of linked argument pairs through `argparse`?  You might as well remove all the talk about postgres and supermarkets, it is distracting from that.  Nothing wrong with keeping store1, checkpoint_store1, etc as example pairs though.

Comment: is the list of checkpoint_store1, checkpoint_store2 fixed per store?  does it ever change?  if not, could you not just pass in the --store1, --store2 (or whatever format you end up using) and let the program lookup the corresponding checkpoint value?  Asking the user to remember which checkpoint goes with which store seems error prone.  And, also makes your argparsing more complicated.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I need @JLPeyret. But how do I let the program lookup the checkpoint? I just want to pass the stores and avoid any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, I think you need to use *positional* argparse arguments to have them repeat (i.e. you dont have --store option names for them).  Or maybe I am confusing with optparse, using mostly Click these days.

The [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) part of the doc covers that so it looks like you could use `--store` too.  Not super clear with examples.  That said, that's more typing for the users, so I'd go with positionals.

```
import argparse

#the existing dictionary
lookup = {'store1': 'checkpoint_store1', 'store2': 'checkpoint_store2','store3': 'checkpoint_store3'}

#from doc @ https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#example
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some stores.')

#Option 1 your loop checks for valid stores
# parser.add_argument('stores', type=str, nargs='+', help='stores')

#Option2 argparse checks for valid stores
parser.add_argument('stores', type=str, nargs='+', help='stores', choices=lookup.keys())

args = parser.parse_args()
user_stores = args.stores
dict_stores = {}

#check in loop
for store in user_stores:
    try:
        dict_stores[store] = lookup[store]
    #pragma: no cover pylint: disable=unused-variable
    except (KeyError,) as e: 
        print(f" unknown store {store}. known : {' '.join(lookup.keys())}")

# if you use argparse to check this can be simplified to
# dict_stores[store] = {store: lookup[store] for store in user_stores}


print(f"{dict_stores}")
```

#### output:

```
(venv38) me@explore$ py test_301_arg.py store1 store2
{'store1': 'checkpoint_store1', 'store2': 'checkpoint_store2'}


(venv38) me@explore$ py test_301_arg.py store1 store4
usage: test_301_arg.py [-h] {store1,store2,store3} [{store1,store2,store3} ...]
test_301_arg.py: error: argument stores: invalid choice: 'store4' (choose from 'store1', 'store2', 'store3')


(venv38) me@explore$ py test_301_arg.py --help
usage: test_301_arg.py [-h] {store1,store2,store3} [{store1,store2,store3} ...]

Process some stores.

positional arguments:
  {store1,store2,store3}
                        stores

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need - thank you. Can I make the existing dictionary come from the checkpoint table I have in the PostgreSQL DB?  This would make it even more dynamic..The table has the following columns: checkpoint_id and checkpoint_name (checkpoint_store1, checkpoint_store2, etc)

Comment: probably.  if the store1/checkpoint_store1 associations exist in postgres, I see no reason you couldn't populate `lookup` dynamically.  in fact, that would be a much more robust approach than hardcoding.

Comment: Yeah this table only has the checkpoint name column unfortunately, not the store. I will only find checkpoint_store2, checkpoint_store3, etc under the column checkpoint_name. Can I still do that from the checkpoint name only you reckon?

Comment: that's more of a database data question.  without knowing your db schema it is hard to say.  maybe you need to join to another table.  there may be a `store_id` column in there somewhere.  afraid that's not a question StackOverflow is going to be able to help with, maybe ask your database folk?  first query the data in pure sql to the point you have both columns in the results, then you can see about loading a Python dict with it.

Comment: last thing *scans for store transactions in a PostgreSQL table by making use of REGEX patterns* makes my SQL-coder self wince a bit.  be careful there that you have appropriate indexes to have this perform reasonably well if the tables have lots of rows.  keep in mind:  a production database may have lots more than the test databases do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233571/discussion-between-err-and-jl-peyret).

Answer (score 1):

I've found it convenient to use a structure which splits on `,` to read a list of possibilities

```py
def parse_args(args_external=None):
    """ build an arguments object with required attributes from user input """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Example Program",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--foo",
        default="",
        help="comma-separated collection of bars")

    arguments = parser.parse_args(args_external)  # enables automated testing (otherwise None -> sys.argv)

    _foo = []
    for bar in arguments.foo.split(","):
        if not bar:  # allow skipping ,,
            continue
        validatebar(bar)  # sys.exit with message if invalid
    arguments.foo = _foo  # clobber the original reference
```

this is consumed like

```sh
python3 ./myscript.py --foo bar1,bar2,bar3
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: simply read a JSON configuration file, perhaps making the argument either the filename or a trigger for `stdin`

```py
import json

    ...
    with open(path_config) as fh:
        config = json.load(fh)  # config is now a Python dict
```